# Extra parenthesis '{' is coming in JSON output from SQL server

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

I am new in JSON & want to generate JSON output directly from SQL server.

But while calling SP from C#.net, i am getting an extra '{' bracket in the start.
And while trying to store the JSON into SQL, it is giving error saying it is not valid JSON.

Below is my code from Stored procedure.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
As 
BEGIN

SELECT Trucknumber,
        (
        select * from TruckDetails
        where TruckId = Truckmaster.TruckId
        FOR JSON AUTO
        ) AS CompData  
    FROM Truckmaster
Where TruckNumber = 'HP09A3487' 
FOR JSON AUTO

END
```

C# Code------------------------------------

```
public StringBuilder RunStoredProcedureWithString(string strSPName)
        {
            StringBuilder jsonResult = new StringBuilder();

            var queryWithForJson = "exec " + strSPName;
            var conn = new SqlConnection(GenerateConnectionString(_DBName));
            var cmdNew = new SqlCommand(queryWithForJson, conn);
            conn.Open();
            var reader = cmdNew.ExecuteReader();
            if (!reader.HasRows)
            {
                jsonResult.Append("[]");
            }
            else
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   jsonResult.Append(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                }
            }
            return jsonResult;
        }
```

Calling Stored procedure.

```
 var strJson = objDBSupport.RunStoredProcedureWithString("GetData");
 if(strJson.Length > 0)
 {
//Success
 }
```

Output desired & also coming in SQL.

```json
[{"Trucknumber":"HP09A3487","CompData":[{"TruckId":37886,"CompNo":1,"Capacity":6000},{"TruckId":37886,"CompNo":2,"Capacity":4000},{"TruckId":37886,"CompNo":3,"Capacity":3000},{"TruckId":37886,"CompNo":4,"Capacity":5000}]}]
```

Output coming in C# with extra '{', which is invalid for inserting into another Table.

```json
{[{"Trucknumber":"HP09A3487","CompData":[{"TruckId":37886,"CompNo":1,"Capacity":6000},{"TruckId":37886,"CompNo":2,"Capacity":4000},{"TruckId":37886,"CompNo":3,"Capacity":3000},{"TruckId":37886,"CompNo":4,"Capacity":5000}]}]}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: C# doesn't modify results. Your code manipulates a `jsonResult` object though, whose definition is missing. If that's a JObject, it's *the application code* that "adds" the extra braces - JObject is serialized as a JavaScript object

Comment: Side point: your connection, command and reader need `using` blocks to dispose them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reproduced your setup but couldn't reproduce any problem. I suspect you're doing this to look at your data:

[image]

Visual Studio is adding the outermost `{ }` purely for display purposes in the debugger. They aren't part of your data. Here my data definitely has no {} in:

[image]

It does this to every object you inspect:

[image]

A `StringBuilder` has an overriden `ToString` that shows the contents instead of the type name (the default behavior of `object`'s `ToString`), so the contents of the SB appear in the debugger tooltip, inside of `{ }`. Because `{` looks like JSON you're getting confused..

---

See the difference in the immediate window, in "object representation" versus "string representation"

[image]

Note, those `\` before the `"` in the string rep aren't in your data either; they're added when visualizing strings to make it easier to paste a string into code as a literal

---

If you want to truly look at your data without these manipulations, put it into a string and then click the magifying glass in the tooltip of the StringBuilder (there are various options for visualizing it):

[image]

You see the string in a textbox, as you would if you wrote it to a file and opened it in Notepad

[image]

<sup>If this visualization confusion isn't the actual problem, post a screenshot of how youre determining your data has extra {} so we can see your thought process and work back from it</sup>

Comment: Thanks Caius, I haven't noticed that. Since my another set of code for inserting this JSON data into database was giving error for invalid JSON. I have rectified the same now.